# добавить класс по клику на чиcтом JS

Tags: javascript

необходимо добавить класс по клику на элемент с id. почему-то не срабатывает, в чем ошибка?

```
<div id="change-color" class="box2">
    <div id="c1" class="cube"></div>
    <div id="c2" class="cube"></div>
    <div id="c3" class="cube"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var c1 = document.getElementById('c1');
c1.addEventListener('click', cgangeBG);

function cgangeBG(){
    this.classList.toggle('pink');
}
```

CSS:

```
.pink{
    background:pink;
}
```

вот полный код [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/4egqf2yt/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в расположении CSS. Так как в css описание класса `.pink` идет **до** класса `.cube`, то при использовании их вместе на одном элементе, свойства из класса `.cude` будут переписывать свойства из класса `.pink`. Что и происходит со свойством `background`

```js
var container = document.getElementById('messages-container');
    container.onclick = function(event) {
      if (!event.target.classList.contains('remove-button')) return;
      event.target.parentNode.hidden = !event.target.parentNode.hidden;
    };
    
var c1 = document.getElementById('c1');
c1.addEventListener('click', cgangeBG);
 
function cgangeBG(){
    this.classList.toggle('pink');
}
```

```css
.clear{clear:both;}
.box1 div{
  float:left;
  margin:0 1%;
}
.remove-button{
  cursor:pointer;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  border:none;
  color:#fff;
  background:#DE1111;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.box2 div{
  float:left;
  
}
.cube{ /*сначала общие настройки*/
  background:lightgrey;
  height:40px;
  width:40px;
  margin:25px 1%;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.pink{ /*потом те которые могут меняться*/
  background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="messages-container" class="box1">
    <div>     
      <p>text1</p>
      <button class="remove-button">x</button>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <p>tex2</p>
      <button class="remove-button">x</button>
     </div>
   
   <div>      
      <p>text3</p>
      <button class="remove-button">x</button>
    </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="clear"></div>
 
 <div id="change-color" class="box2">
   <div id="c1" class="cube"></div>
   <div id="c2" class="cube"></div>
   <div id="c3" class="cube"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: понятно. спасибо!

Comment: а если добавить для всех элементов, то не работает...https://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/4egqf2yt/4/

Comment: @MarinaVoronova, все потому, что вы опять выбираете коллекцию: `var cube = document.getElementsByClassName('cube');`, а _addEventListener_ работает с **конкретным** элементом.